# how to scale the plot of PDF (t-distribution)

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics

The directions in my book say: "To sketch the t distribution in Figure 3.11, simply multiply the abscissa t value by the scale factor and plot this against the ordinate of t at that point." So basically, the scale factor is given. The x values should be multiplied by the scaled factor while the y should remain the same. It seems like all it is, we are stretching the plot of t distribution by the scale factor. How do I create a plot like this? For a normal t-distribution, I would use the following code for plotting. But how do I produce a plot as described above?

```
Plot[PDF[StudentTDistribution[1], x], {x, -8, 8 }]
```

Edit: I just realized that I also need to scale the whole graph by the scale parameter: i.e. the shape remains the same, but I need to operate on much larger values of x

Comment: Plot[PDF[StudentTDistribution[1], x/scalefactor], {x, -8, 8}]?

Comment: @Algohi, thanks! what if I wanted to change the scale for x and y? in other words, to see exactly the same plot (shape) of data, but on bigger scale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly but you can try this:

```
f[sclx_, scly_] := scly*PDF[StudentTDistribution[1], x/sclx]
Plot[{f[1, 1], f[2, 3]}, {x, -8, 8}]
```

[image]

Comment: How can both of these curves be a valid pdf?

Comment: Only one is valid pdf.

Comment: What is the other?

Comment: The other is a function resulted from the first one.

Comment: \\\\\ . :-) . ////